# Why won't basic spring 4 sample run with Eclipse kepler?

Tags: java, eclipse, spring

I am using the sample project code here that i've downloaded from the following:
http://javahash.com/spring-4-mvc-hello-world-tutorial-full-example/

Direct link here:
http://javahash.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/Spring4MVCHelloWorld.zip

I have Eclipse Kepler SR2 (J2EE), Tomcat 7 64-bit, Java 7.

The project does not appear to be a web project, so I add "Dynamic Web Module" version 3.0 and "Java" (version 1.7) to it. I right click, maven install, which appears to run fine. When I try to actually deploy it on tomcat, it does not give any errors in the console, but when the browser window pops up it shows a 404

```
http://localhost:8080/Spring4MVCHelloWorld/



HTTP Status 404 - /Spring4MVCHelloWorld/

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

type Status report

message /Spring4MVCHelloWorld/

description The requested resource is not available.


--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Apache Tomcat/6.0.39
```

That said, how do I get this "basic" example running in eclipse? Anyone able to get this working successfully? It feels like it should be more trivial than the 5 hours I've spent on trying to get this sample code working to no avail.

UPDATE:
Still continues to fail despite using Tomcat 7.0 server.

1. Download the sample, extract contents to workspace directory.
2. "Import Existing Project" in Eclipse
3. Since there is no "Run On Server" option, I right click on the imported project directory and hit "Properties".
4. I go to "Project Facets" and check 2 things: "Dynamic Web Module" (3.0) and "Java" (1.7) and hit apply then "Ok".
5. I right click on the project Spring4MVCHelloWorld and click "Maven"->"Update Project".  Then I click "Run On Server".
6. There are no errors in the console, but the web browser that pops up in eclipse shows a HTTP STATUS 404.

I tried going to:

```
http://localhost:8080/Spring4MVCHelloWord/hello
```

and the same:

HTTP Status 404 - /Spring4MVCHelloWorld/hello

shows up, but the tomcat shows up as:

Apache Tomcat/7.0.53

Note that this is the 64-bit version. What steps am I missing? How do I get around this silent failing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from what [Dimitri](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22953751/438154) stated, your log seems to indicate that you are using

```
Apache Tomcat/6.0.39
```

That [version of Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html) does not support `ServletContainerInitializer` which your Spring web application depends on for configuration. Upgrade to a Tomcat version 7+.

---

It seems like the Maven update doesn't work for you (or for me).

First, go into `Properties -> Deployment Assembly`. You need to get rid of `Web Content` if it's there and add `src/main/webapp` (which is a maven convention). You also need to add the Maven Dependencies as shown below.

[image]

Finally, and this might not be necessary, delete the `web.xml` provided to you and re-create it by selecting and right clicking `Deployment Descriptor` in the Project Explorer and clicking `Generate Deployment Descriptor Stub`.

Also, make sure your `Java Build Path` in the `Properties` has a Java 7+ version of the JRE.

Comment: Using 64-bit Tomcat v7.0, same issue.

Comment: @Rolando Even with Dimitri' s changes?

Comment: I can successfully run it, though I am not sure if it is really working. When going to the link: http://localhost:8080/Spring4MVCHelloWorld/hello/?name=JavaHash, I am seeing "Hello : ${name}", is something preventing the Java from being loaded properly?

Comment: @Rolando The `${name}` is known as Expression Language. There are a number of reasons for it not to render. You can look for those on Stackoverflow. Check first what the version of your `web-app` is in the application's `web.xml`. It should be 3.0 (2.5+ at least).

Comment: Updating the version in web.xml appears to work. Though if I modified it to include the "dispatcherservlet" despite having the correct dispatcher-servlet.xml file in the guide, it fails: 
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class> Not sure why this is the case, but it works now.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see your controller only maps to `/hello`, which means your URL should be:

```
http://localhost:8080/Spring4MVCHelloWorld/hello
```

Another thing that might be interesting to you is that if your having problems with certain project facets (like **Dynamic Web Module**) not being recognized, you can usually fix them by righ clicking your project, opening the **Maven** menu and choosing **Update Project**.

Comment: Does not appear to resolve the issue, same error, but with Apache Tomcat/7.0.53 instead of Apache Tomcat 6.